# UIView default properties and custom properties

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller

I created UIView with default properties

```
var color =  Label.Color.black { didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() }}
var count =  Label.Count.one.rawValue   { didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() }}
var shading =  Label.Shading.empty   { didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() }}
var shape =  Label.Shape.triangle { didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() }}
var isSelected = false
```

And then I add some subviews using the same UIView in ViewController

```
func addCardsOnGridView() {
    grid.frame = cardsView.bounds
    grid.cellCount = game.cardsOnDeck.count
    for cardView in cardsView.subviews{

        cardView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    for index in 0..<grid.cellCount {
        if let cellFrame = grid[index] {
            let card = game.cardsOnDeck[index]
            let cardView = CardsView(frame: cellFrame.insetBy(dx: CardSize.inset, dy: CardSize.inset))
            cardView.color = card.label.color
            cardView.count = card.label.count.rawValue
            cardView.shape = card.label.shape
            cardView.shading = card.label.shading
            //cardView.isSelected = card.isSelected
            //print(cardsView.isSelected)
            cardsView.addSubview(cardView)

        } else {
            print("grid[\(index)] doecnt exist")
        }
    }
}
```

and then I got this UIView with default comes as superview and subviews above superview:

[image: UIView with default comes as superview and subviews above superview]

How can I remove view with default UIView properties and redraw with custom properties?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Which view is the problem?

Comment: @Edward so do use big triangle? It’s view with default properties . And we have 24 smaller views with custom views . I’d like to know how to remove that view with big triangle and appear only custom views

Comment: So I want to override default values of UIView with custom values

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question completely. What I understand is that you want to get specific view like triangle view.

One way to achieve this is by assigning `tag` to every subview like below when you are adding them in mainView

```
aView.tag = 6
```

and then when you want to get a subview, you can get using `viewWithTag` function like below

```
if let aCustomView = mainView.viewWithTag(6) as? CustomView {
   aCustomView.myColor = .blue
}
```

An other way to get custom view is by looping thought subview and try to cast view into custom class like below

```
mainView.subviews.forEach({ (aView) in
  if aView.tag == 6,
     let customView = aView as? CustomView {
        customView.myColor = .blue
  }
})
```